# Typescript interface for default export

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very basic folder structure for config files like this:

```
/config
  /button
  /colors
  /index
```

Code looks like this:

**colors.ts**

```
export interface Colors {
  [key: string]: string,
}

export default {
  black: '#111',
  grey: '#999',
  green: '#4c8857',
  red: '#bd1414',
  white: '#fff',
};
```

**index.ts**

```
import colors from './colors';

export default {
  button,
  colors,
};
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module './colors'. '/xxxxx/styles/config/colors.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I'm completely new to Typescript and can't find any tutorials or examples online that clearly explain what I've done wrong here.

Comment: if you're trying to import the colors interface, I'm fairly certain it should be `ìmport {Colors} from './colors';`

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 problems: you are not importing the interface properly because of a case error:

```
import colors from './colors';
export interface Colors {
```

try

`import {Colors} from './colors';`

But here you are simply exporting the "Colors" interface, not the object of colours.

the code you might like would be something like:

```
export interface Colors {
  [key: string]: string,
}

export const defaultColors: Colors = {
  black: '#111',
  grey: '#999',
  green: '#4c8857',
  red: '#bd1414',
  white: '#fff',
};
```

Then import it

```
import {defaultColors} from './colors'
```

Note: if you struggle with imports, I strongly advise to use an IDE like Webstorm which can automatically import the right dependencies.

Comment: I'll give this a go (in an hour, just need to step out for a bit!)

Comment: This does indeed work. In this situation though, is it better to not define the interface and simply let Typescript infer the types for me as Mark Atkinson suggests? It would be a bit cleaner, but with the .ts filenames I get the error I originally described without adding the interface myself.

Comment: I strongly suggest to type everything, this will help you to maintain the project in the long term. If you don't, typescript will either infer it to `any` or possibly to `[key: string]: string;` it's risky, as this won't prevent you to add a number colour by mistake like for instance: `black: 00000`.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you let Typescript infer the types for you. You are likely to have more accurate types than defining an interface with the `[key: string]: string`.

If you don't want to use a `default` export I would suggest just exporting the following:

```
export const Colors = {
  black: '#111',
  grey: '#999',
  green: '#4c8857',
  red: '#bd1414',
  white: '#fff',
};
```

You would then import `import { Colors } from './colors'`

If colors is the only/main thing in the `colors` file then you can go ahead and export using `default` like so:

```
const colors = {
  black: '#111',
  grey: '#999',
  green: '#4c8857',
  red: '#bd1414',
  white: '#fff',
};

export default colors;
```

You would then import `import Colors from './colors'`

Comment: If I don't define an interface or any types, I still get the error: Could not find a declaration file for module... How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create your ts file with

1. Interface: can be imported or in the same file
2. Create your variable to be exported and make sure you use the interface here
3. Export your variable as default, and the interface is toed to it

```
interface Colors {
  [key: string]: string,
}

const defaultColors: Colors = {
  black: '#111',
  grey: '#999',
  green: '#4c8857',
  red: '#bd1414',
  white: '#fff',
};

export default defaultColors
```